# adding a control to another control in caliburn micro

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I am learning Caliburn Micro and I created a project similar to this tutorial :

http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Basic%20Configuration%2c%20Actions%20and%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation

Now I want to create another user control and add it to the above model. so I created a simple user control which is essentially the same as shellViewModel in the tutorial. The view and view model are the same as shellViewModel and ShellView, but with a different name.

When I run application, I can see that view is shown on screen, but it is not bind to ViewModel. Should I do any changes to bootstrap so this works?

More information:
I have created a wpf project similar to tutorial as explained above.
It works well.

I add a new user control to project and names it NewUCView. 
So I have the following files in my project:

NewUCView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="CaliburnMicroTest.NewUCView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="Name" />
    <Button x:Name="SayHello"
            Content="Click Me" />
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

NewUCView.xaml.cs

```
namespace CaliburnMicroTest
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for NewUC.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class NewUCView : UserControl
    {
         public NewUCView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

NewUCViewModel.cs

```
namespace CaliburnMicroTest
{
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Windows;

   using global::Caliburn.Micro;

   /// <summary>
   /// TODO: Update summary.
   /// </summary>
   public class NewUCViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
   {
       string name;

       public string Name
       {
           get { return name; }
           set
           {
               name = value;
               NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Name);
               NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanSayHello);
            }
       }

       public bool CanSayHello
       {
           get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name); }
       }

        public void SayHello()
       {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Hello {0}!", Name)); //Don't do this in real life :)
        }
   }
}
```

I changed the ShellView as follow and add a reference  to NewUCView into it.

```
 <StackPanel>
    <my:NewUCView x:Name="newUC" />
    <TextBox x:Name="Name" />
    <Button x:Name="SayHello"
            Content="Click Me" />

</StackPanel>
```

also changed the ShellViewModel to have a property called newUC which is a NewUCViewModel as follow:

```
    private NewUCViewModel newUC=new NewUCViewModel();
    public  NewUCViewModel NewUC
    {
        get
        {
            return newUC;
        }

    }
```

But when I run this application and press the first click me (which is on user control), it doesn't work. The other button (which is on ShellView) works.

Comment: Please see the question as I add code to it. I can uploaad project, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add the usercontrol directly to the view, and let the caliburn framework do that for you.
You need to add a placeholder to your main view and bind it to the property that represents your ViewModel:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="NewUC"/>
```

Since caliburn can resolve data bindings by looking to the name of the Control, in my code the framework will bind the NewUCView with the NewUCViewModel that is named, in your example, NewUC, and show an instance of NewUCView inside the ContentControl palceholder.